# A Fundamental Connectwall

Tags: knowledge, connect-wall

These words can be grouped into four groups of four words, with a connection between all of the four groups. What is the connection?

|  |  |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| MARK | BAR | ANGLE | MAMMAL |
| SAUCE | NATURE | CENT | CHANCE |
| MURDER | PENT | EDUCATION | SPY |
| PLACE | SPEED | BURN | THOUGHT |

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The groups are:

> - Second ____
>  NATURE
>  CHANCE
>  THOUGHT
>  PLACE
>
>  - Degree scales
>  MURDER
>  BURN
>  ANGLE
>  EDUCATION
>
>  - Meanings of mole
>  SPY
>  MAMMAL
>  MARK
>  SAUCE
>
>  - Append "meter" (barometer, centimeter, pentameter, speedometer) *(thanks @PDT)*
>  BAR
>  CENT
>  PENT
>  SPEED

The connection between the four groups is:

> SI units (second, degree, mole, meter). The "fundamental" in the title probably refers to them being among the 7 basic SI units, assuming "degree" may be interpreted as "degree Kelvin".

Comment: I am thinking pentameter, speedometer, centimeter, barometer

Comment: I think you are correct otherwise 

Comment: @PDT That's got to be it! I'm embarrassed I had tried attaching "meter" but didn't notice anything.

Comment: I saw this and the degree as a group but I didn’t know about what SI units really were so I couldn’t finish the puzzle before I had something else I needed doing.

Comment: You are correct! Great job.